# Can switching to an SSD resolve this particular issue?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, task-manager

Recently, the Task Manager on my laptop has been indicating
that the HDD is operating at 100% utilization multiple times a day.
I believe this is causing my laptop to slow down, resulting in delayed
tab opening and sluggish keyboard response. Would switching to an
SSD resolve this issue?

**Operating System**: Windows 10

**CPU**: Core i3 10th Gen.

[image]

Comment: SSDs are perhaps one of the best bang-for-your-buck performance increases these days and if you have the funds to make that upgrade I rarely ever see a case where you should not make that upgrade, HOWEVER, you haven't actually presented clear evidence of a problem, and there are bottlenecks on computers other than the drive. We cannot simply say "yes, an SSD will fix that set of problems" for many reasons, and even with more information, I don't know that we can say it'll be a fix. Is there a strong chance it'll generally speed up your computer in ways you can see and feel? Yes.

Comment: Even with an SSD, a decent modern I5 CPU and 40GB of RAM, my disk nearly always reports 100% usage, browser tabs can still lag a bit opening, depending on what else is going on with the system, and there are times when other processes are clearly impacting what I'm currently trying to do.

Comment: So will an SSD solve your problems? We don't know, and we may not actually EVER be able to know unless you just go out and buy and install one.

Comment: @music2myear the 93% RAM ise is a pretty clear indication of a problem. An SSD might help, but the most likely fix is more RAM or finding out what is using it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing an SSD in the extra slot and using it for my OS, my laptop’s performance got a huge boost
and disk usage dropped from 100% to below 10%:

[image]

Comment: With your high memory usage you may find the constant memory overflow into the SSD causes it to die a lot sooner than it otherwise would. As stated in my answer the SSD will (and does) help, but unless you address the RAM problem you are just going to be wearing out the SSD. My advice would be to keep a good backup of the SSD.

Answer (score 2):

An SSD would help, but your underlying issue is RAM.

Your ram is showing as 93% used, which is likely spilling over to using virtual memory on your hard disk. That is causing high usage on your hard disk and in turn is making everything slow in your system.

You should focus first on upgrading your system RAM, but an SSD could also improve performance a lot.